# gRPC gives SIGABRT when starting server with TLS

Tags: c++, grpc, tls1.3

When starting my `gRPC` server with TLS, I'm getting a `SIGABRT`. The code I'm using is:

```
std::shared_ptr<grpc::experimental::FileWatcherCertificateProvider> cert_provider(new grpc::experimental::FileWatcherCertificateProvider(server_key_path, server_cert_path, ca_cert_path, 10));
grpc::experimental::TlsServerCredentialsOptions tlsOpts(cert_provider);
tlsOpts.set_cert_request_type(grpc_ssl_client_certificate_request_type::GRPC_SSL_REQUEST_AND_REQUIRE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_AND_VERIFY);
std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials> tlsCreds = grpc::experimental::TlsServerCredentials(tlsOpts);
builder.AddListeningPort(uri, tlsCreds);
builder.BuildAndStart();
```

`gdb backtrace` shows it's failing an assert in `grpc_tls_certificate_distributor::WatchTlsCertificates()`. If I add `tlsOpts.watch_root_certs()`, it gets past that to another assertion fail in `grpc_core::TlsServerSecurityConnector::UpdateHandshakerFactoryLocked()`.

I don't think I should be forced to have to watch any certs. What is the proper way to set this up? I've done it successfully with `SslServerCredentialsOptions` instead of TlsServerCredentialsOptions, but the SSL interface doesn't have a way to set CRLs.

Comment: Which asserts are failing? Please show the backtrace output.

Comment: It seems, despite what public header says https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/security/tls_credentials_options.h#L68C8-L68C24 the comment from this internal header https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/grpc_tls_credentials_options.h#L77 suggests both watch root and watch identity need to be called for TLS. So of course, that raises the question, what is the name in set_root_cert_name and set_identity_cert_name?